# remove XML node with jQuery .each and $(this)

Tags: jquery, xml

I am looping through some elements using jQuery's .each() and I want to delete a node when it meets certain requirements.  I'm unsure of the syntax for this, I've tried several things:

```
$(this).remove();
$xml.remove(this);
$xml.removeNode(this);
```

...etc.  Having some trouble finding a working example, could somebody point me in the right direction?  I'm assuming it's simple, I just haven't been able to find the correct syntax.  Got a non-working fiddle below.

http://jsfiddle.net/SHNpn/

Thanks

Comment: your non working script is due to the missing tags {} after the IF statment i dont know about the rest

Comment: Those aren't always needed.  I usually leave them out when in a hurry and only using single line actions.  Thanks though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because the call to `remove()` only removes the element from the DOM. It does not remove it from your `$siblings` jQuery object.

If you call `find()` again to rematch the siblings after removing the `alex` node, you will get the expected results:

```js
var $xml = $(xmlString);
var $siblings = $xml.find("sibling");

$siblings.each(function(){
    var name = $(this).attr("name");
    if (name == "alex")
        $(this).remove();
});

// Here, the "alex" element is not in the DOM, but still part of $siblings.

$xml.find("sibling").each(function(){
    var name = $(this).attr("name");
    console.log(name);
});

// Since we're calling find() again, the code above will only print "bob".
```

You will find an updated fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/SHNpn/2/).